# Calculate line integral along cubes.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

Let the continuous closed path $C$ consist of the two curves $C_1$ and $C_2$, where $C_1$ goes from $(0, 0, 0)$ to $(1, 1, 1)$ by following the edges of the cube $0 \le x \le 1, 0 \le y \le 1, 0 \le z \le 1$ from $(0, 0, 0)$ to $(0, 0, 1)$ to $(0, 1, 1)$ to $(1, 1, 1)$ and $C_2$ goes from $(1, 1, 1)$ to $(0, 0, 0)$ directly along the diagonal.

If I have a vector field $F = y
^2
i − z^
2
j + x^
2 k$, could someone please tell me how to calculate its line integral $\int F\cdot dr$ along both $C_1$ and $C_2$. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you want to do it parametrise the curves. I will walk you through $C_2$.

The parametrisation is $\mathbf{r}:U\subset\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $\mathbf{r}(t)=(t,t,t)$. The domain will be $U=\left[0, \sqrt 3\right]$ because the length of the diagonal, by Pythagoras' theorem, is $\sqrt{1^2+1^2+1^2}$.

You want to evaluate F at every point on this line and add these values together. In other words, you want to integrate $F(\mathbf{r})$ over the domain $U$.

The line integral can be written as $\int_UF\big(\mathbf r(t)\big)\mathbf r'(t)\mathrm dt$ where $\mathbf{r}'(t)=\frac{\mathrm d\mathbf{r}}{\mathrm dt}$

You can think of $\mathbf r'(t)\mathrm dt$ as essentially the infinitesimally small arc length $\mathrm d\mathbf{r}$.

Calculating the derivative gives $\mathbf{r}'(t)=(1,1,1)$
Substituting everything in gives $$\int_0^\sqrt{3}F(t,t,t)\cdot(1,1,1)\mathrm dt = 
\\ \int_0^\sqrt{3}\left(t^2, -t^2, t^2\right)\cdot(1,1,1)\mathrm dt
\\ \int_0^\sqrt{3}t^2dt = \frac{1}{3}\left[t^3\right]_0^\sqrt{3} = \sqrt{3}$$

The process is the same for $C_1$, but you will need to split it into three separate lines first, each with its own parametrisation and then add the results together.